# Why there is such big results of value?

Tags: c

I faced with a problem when solving a task from university.
The task is to do the algorithm of calculating and the program on C for determinating function's value, which is:

```
F = (E_1 - E_2 + E_3) / (E_1 * E_3)
```

where

```
E_1 = sin(x + 3), E_2 = tg(a), E_3 = a^x + b
```

whereas x, a, b - the users input.

The problem is in namely output! The numbers of there very big and inappropriate! The code below:

```
int main()
{
    int x, a, b;
    
    printf("Put the x value: ");
    x = scanf("%i", &x); //x = 1

    printf("Put the a value: ");
    a = scanf("%i", &a); //a = 1

    printf("Put the b value: ");
    b = scanf("%i", &b); //b = 1

    double E_1 = sin(x + 3); 
    double E_2 = tan(a);
    double E_3 = pow(a, x) + b;
    double F = (E_1 - E_2 + E_3) / (E_1 * E_3);

    printf("Then, the F = %i", &F);

    return 0; 
}
```

And, for example, if x, a, b = 1, the output is 5502604, which is false!

Comment: ```printf("Then, the F = %i", &F);``` should be ```printf("Then, the F = %f", &F);```

Comment: F is a double, but your format string doesn't match that. Turn on -Wformat-type-confusion or it's equivalent so the compiler detects that.

Comment: `&F` is an address, not an integer. And `F` is a double anyway. Try `printf("Then, the F = %f", F);` Turn up your compiler warnings. Besides the options mentioned by user1937198, you might also add `-Wall -Wextra`

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of problems in the posted code.

```
int x;
printf("Put the x value: ");
x = scanf("%i", &x); //x = 1
```

`scanf` returns the number of times a value is correctly assigned to one of its argument pointers or EOF if end-of-file (or an input error) occurs before any values are stored. So, this line and the others will always assign 1 (or 0, or EOF, which is usually -1, if an error occurs) to the variables, whatever values the user entered.

It's unclear why the variables `x`, `a` and `b` are declared as `int`s rather than `double`s.

```
double F = /* ... */;

printf("Then, the F = %i", &F);
//                    ^^   ^^
```

Here the wrong format (`%i` is used for integers, a `double` requires `%f` or `%lf`) specifier it's used and the wrong value is passed (the address of `F` instead of `F`).

Comment: nothing changed... The result after corrections is now fixed and 0.207591 .....

Comment: @Alex What [corrections](https://godbolt.org/z/cWsq34)? What are the sample inputs and the expected output?

Comment: there's no inputs are value. All you input - the result is 0.207591....

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If I'm not mistaken, you have essentially three tasks (not in the following order): to [print](https://godbolt.org/z/T19rda) a `double` value, to [retrieve](https://godbolt.org/z/f4hP5d) some valid numbers from the standard input and to [evaluate](https://godbolt.org/z/qe1ddW) a mathematical function. Which one is the one you are having troubles with?